# Can we delete the older version jquery libraries from jquery_update module?

Tags: javascript

The recent version of jquery_update module has 1.10 version of jquery library. And it also has older versions in it. Can we delete these older version files from the module? Will there be any problem if i delete them from the module directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete them, as long as nothing is trying to use them, but they'll be restored when the module is updated.

They're only a few hundred kb between them, common sense might suggest to leave them where they are.